# WPF performance problem with CommandManager

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

We've created a new, quite complex, WPF application from the ground up and have run into a performance problem as the number of commands registered with the CommandManager increase. We're using simple lightweight commands in our MVVM implementation, however the third party controls we're using (Infragistics) do not, and call CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding liberally to add RoutedCommands. The performance problem manifests itself as a perceived sluggishness in the UI when responding to user input, for example tabbing between controls is slow, text input is 'jerky' and popup animation is 'clunky'. When the app is first fired up the UI is snappy. As more screens containing Infragistics grids are opened the performance deteriorates.

Internally, the CommandManager has a private field named _requerySuggestedHandlers, which is a List< WeakReference>. I've used reflection to get a reference to this collection, and I've noticed that when I call .Clear(), the responsiveness of the UI improves back to its initial state. Obviously I don't want to go round clearing collections that I know little about, especially using reflection (!) but I did it to see if it would cure the performance problems, and voila it did.

Normally, this situation would clean itself up after a certain amount of time passes. However, the collection of WeakReferences (_requerySuggestedHandlers) will only get trimmed once a garbage collection is initiated, which is non-deterministic. Because of this, when we close down windows containing grids (Infragistics XamDataGrid), the CanExecute property for 'dead' grid commands continue to be evaluated unnecessarily, long after the window is closed. This also means that if we close down a number of windows, the performance is still sluggish until a garbage collect is initiated. I understand that this can happen on allocation, and I've seen that myself because if I open a further window this causes the initial memory (from the disposed Windows) to be collected and performance returns to normal.

So, given the above, here are my questions:

1. How, and from where, does CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() get called? I haven't found any documentation on MSDN that explains this in any great detail. I hooked up to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event and it looks like it's being called whenever controls lose focus.
2. Is is possible to suppress CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() being called in response to user input?
3. Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, how have you avoided it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like one of the rare cases where deterministically calling `GC.Collect()` is the right thing to do.  The ordinary argument against it is that the garbage collector is smarter than you are.  But when you're dealing with `WeakReference` objects, you enter territory where you may know something that the garbage collector doesn't.  Kicking off garbage collection is *certainly* better than clearing `_requerySuggestedHandlers` - among other things, it won't do anything to the `WeakReference` objects that point to controls that are still alive.

I'd choose this over trying to figure out how to suppress `RequerySuggested`, since that would screw up the behavior of those commands that you still care about.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I was headed that way after reading an article on memory management by Jeffrey Richter on MSDN. Previously I wouldn't have ever considered calling GC.Collect because I thought it was bad practise, but I now understand that it is perfectly acceptable in situations such as this where you know more about the behaviour of the application than the GC.